# Change property file located in src/test/resources

Tags: java, apache, maven, junit4

I'm exploring Apache Common Configuration and want to make a test that just read/write properties from/to xml file located in src/test/resources from the test.
So far, I'm reading with no problems but cannot write anything to this file. 
If I change the location of the file from scr/test/resources to another location in the file system (example: c:/test), everything works fine.
Can you please help me with this ?

EDIT

Here is what I had tried so far:

```
    @Test
public void test() throws ConfigurationException {
    //First with data.xml located in src/test/resources
    XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("data.xml");

    List<Object> rows = config.getList("user.username");
    System.out.println(rows);

    //This is not working
    config.setProperty("user.username", "FromTest");
    config.save();      

    // Second with data.xml in different location
    XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("c:/temp/data.xml");

    List<Object> rows = config.getList("user.username");
    System.out.println(rows);   

    //This works
    config.setProperty("user.username", "FromTest");
    config.save();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why would you want to do so?

Comment: At first, to try the Apache Configuration API but now, I want to know why this is not working and I cannot update the file located in test/resources. It's interesting that I can read from it but cannot write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't provide much insight about the running context, but from the *src/test/resources* path, I guess you work with Maven.
If this is true, this is what happens:

1. Maven copies resources to *target/test-classes*
2. the test method operates on the copied resources, thus *target/test-classes/data.xml*

If you check this file, it works. I just looked at the source file, not the file actually read from your code.

The difference with the second test, *c:/temp/data.xml*, is that the former is a relative path, while the latter is absolute, and not under Maven's scope.

Comment: I just saw the file located in target/test-clsses/data.xml and it really is changed. Thanks!